# Not able to push frida server in Android 8.1 hosted on Genymotion

Tags: android, adb, genymotion, frida, kali-linux

I am trying to push frida-server in android version8.1 API 27 hosted on Genymotion (emulator Version 3.5.1) but i am getting this error

```
┌──(kali㉿kali)-[~/frida_files]
└─$  adb push frida-serverx86 /sdcard/
adb: error: failed to read copy response
frida-serverx86: 1 file pushed, 0 skipped. 10.6 MB/s (51595900 bytes in 4.663s)
adb: error: failed to read copy response

frida-server version is frida-server-16.1.3-android-x86.xz
```

i tried reinstalling adb and installed frida-server again unziped it named frida-serverx86 again tried pushing it its not working, I also tried with other andorid versions like 7.1

How can i resolve this?

Comment: Could be an incompatibility of the adb version you use with Genymotion. Better use adb version that is included in Genymotion package. Or just use a physical rooted device, that is always best.

Comment: No, because I am able to use adb push command for uploading burp ca certificates

Comment: Then try to push it to a different folder, The sdcard folder is not suitable as you can not execute binaries from there (it is mounted with noexec flag).

Comment: Yes I cannot execute the file from sdcard but moving to the target folder like in this case to /data/local/tmp/ doesn't work in most of the cases so i tried to push it in sdcard to move it later to target directory. how can i know in which folder i can push it?

Comment: Could be a Genymotion bug. BTW: you are pushing the xz archive, but Android usually can not decompress that archive type, so I would recommend to first decompress the binary and then push it. Unfortunately this should not have an effect on your problem. In the end I prefer physical devices for using frida, especially as a lot of apps refuse to work on emulators.